# dual monitor not working ( both connected but one monitor(main) showing just black window )

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Windows 10 education

NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 2070 ( driver is installed well )

Left one S27D850
Right one M2352D

I am using dual monitors.
one(Left) is connected to **DP port** and the other one(Right) is connected to **HDMI port**.
Both of them are connected to graphic cards ( not motherboard ).

The problem is that the Left one "sometimes" **shows black window** when it is connected to DP port. It is sure that both are connected since I can move things from left window(black) to right window.

It shows well when it is connected to HDMI port but there's only one HDMI port for graphic card... and the right one is quite old one and it only has HDMI port so one HDMI port connected to graphic card is only for the right one.

I said "sometimes" since sometimes the left one shows well and it often shows black window when I locked the screen for a while.

Sometimes it is okay when I connected again and reboot the computer but sometimes it still does not work....

I tried many other cables !! several several times ( same black window result )
and connected my display to other different computers with same cable and it works fine!!=> It might be problem of the board of my computer.

Is there any ways to solve this problem? I waste a lot of time whenever I come to work.

Comment: You can buy an HDMI to DVI [adapter](https://www.amazon.com/Directional-Adapter-Compatible-Raspberry-Graphics/dp/B07D6RL3VN/ref=sr_1_2_sspa) (Nvidia RTX 2070 should have a DVI port) to connect the LG M2352D and leave the HDMI for the Samsung S27D850

Comment: @spike_66 Thank you for your answer! but do you know why my connections sometimes work and not work? whenever I come to work, it doesn't work. I should unplug and plug and reboot again...

Comment: You have an excellent graphics card and the S27D850 is a very good monitor that should work perfectly connected to a DP port. I have no idea why it doesn't. Anyhow I think that by connecting the S27D850 to your graphics card HDMI port and the M2352D to the DVI or DP port (using an adapter) you should be able to solve this issue